# What's different between pod 'GoogleAnalytics' and pod 'Firebase/Analytics'?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I want to add Firebase Cloud messaging to a project. As the guideline in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client I need to add to Podfile:

```
# Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

# Add the pod for Firebase Cloud Messaging
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

But I see in the project already has

```
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
```

So should I keep both `pod 'GoogleAnalytics'` and `pod 'Firebase/Analytics'` or just keep `pod 'GoogleAnalytics'`? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase products including Cloud Messaging integrate with `Firebase/Analytics`. The GoogleAnalytics pod pre-dates Firebase and is not integrated.

(Understood that the naming is confusing.)